# How to find the distance between a point and line joining two points on a sphere?

Tags: analytic-geometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-coordinates

How do I calculate the distance between the line joining the two points on a spherical surface and another point on same surface? I have illustrated my problem in the image below.

[image: Sphere]

In the above illustration, the points A, B and X lies on a spherical surface, I need to find the distance between points (A,B) and X. I am not a mathematics guy. If possible please illustrate me the solution as non-mathematics guys could understand.  Thanks.

Comment: Does this line lie on the sphere or inside the sphere?

Comment: geodesic distance on the sphere?

Comment: Have you tried to set up the standard parametrized integral for the distance between X and an arbitrary point on the line, then vary the integral to find where it obtains it's minimum?

Comment: How are A, B, and X specified?  For example, by latitude and longitude?  And is the distance along the sphere or a straight line through the sphere?

Comment: Use the [Law of Sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#Spherical_case) to get the altitude XC in terms of the length of XB (use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)) and the spherical angle ABX (computed as the angle between planes OAB and OXB; O = center of earth).  Planar angles are computed by converting A, B, X to Cartesian coordinates, using cross-products to obtain the planar normals, and taking their dot products (to get the cosine).  Check that angles ABX and BAX are less than 90 degrees; if not, you need the distance BX or AX instead.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: the points A, B and X are in Latitudes and longitudes. the distance is along the sphere.

Answer (score 9):

This assumes that everything is on the surface of the sphere.  Furthermore I assume the sphere has radius $1$.

Change the coordinates so that $A$ and $B$ are both on the equator of the sphere. For definiteness, move $A$ to $(1,0,0)$ and move $B$ to $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors from the center of the sphere to $A$ and to $B$. This is a linear transformation.

Then what you care about is the latitude of $X$. If $X$ is in the sector of the sphere immediately north or south of the line $AB$, then the answer is just $2\pi \phi$ where $\phi$ is the latitude of $X$. If $X$ is not in that sector then the answer is just the distance to either $A$ or $B$, whichever is closer.

Comment: Isn't what you care about the longitude to determine if `X` is above or below `AB`?

Comment: The least practical answer I have ever read...!

Answer (score 8):

The question is a little ambiguous: the three previous answers used three different interpretations. If the OP wants the surface distance from the point $X$ to the geodesic line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, the answer is straightforward. If the desired distance is between $X$ and the segment $\overline{AB}$, a bit more work is required.

Using longitude ($\theta$) and latitude ($\phi$), let $A=(\theta_A, \phi_A)$, $B=(\theta_B, \phi_B)$, and $X=(\theta_X, \phi_X)$. The direction vectors for these points are 
$$\hat A = (\cos \phi_A \cos \theta_A, \cos \phi_A \sin \theta_A, \sin \phi_A),$$ $$ \hat B = (\cos \phi_B \cos \theta_B, \cos \phi_B \sin \theta_B, \sin \phi_B), $$
$$\hat X = (\cos \phi_X \cos \theta_X, \cos \phi_X \sin \theta_X, \sin \phi_X).$$

Let $\Phi$ be the  distance on the unit sphere between $\hat X$ and the geodesic line passing through $\hat A$ and $\hat B$. Imagine the plane $\mathcal{P}$ passing through $\hat A$, $\hat B$, and the origin, which cuts the unit sphere in half. Then the Euclidean distance of $\hat X$ from  plane $\mathcal{P}$ is $\sin \Phi$. Now let $\hat n$ be a unit normal vector for $\mathcal{P}$, and we have

$$\hat n = \hat A \times \hat B$$
$$\sin \Phi = | \hat n \cdot \hat X |$$

So, if the radius of the original sphere is $R$, then the surface distance from the point $X$ to the geodesic line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ is $R \Phi$.

To determine the distance to the segment $\overline{AB}$, we need to determine whether or not the point of line $\overleftrightarrow{ A B}$ that $ X$ is closest to is between $A$ and $B$. If the closest point is between $A$ and $B$, then the surface distance to the segment is $R \Phi$. Otherwise, the distance to the segment is the distance to the closest endpoint, which is best resolved though the methods described in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) referenced by Ross Millikan. One way to make this determination is to find the point $\hat{X}_{\textrm{proj}}$, the projection of $\hat X$ onto plane $\mathcal{P}$,

$$\hat{X}_{\textrm{proj}} = \hat X - (\hat n \cdot \hat X) \hat n,$$

and then normalize $\hat{X}_{\textrm{proj}}$,

$$\hat x = \frac{\hat{X}_{\textrm{proj}} }{| \hat{X}_{\textrm{proj}} |},$$

So determining whether the point of line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ that $X$ is closest to is between $A$ and $B$ reduces to determining whether $\hat x$ is between $\hat A$ and $\hat B$.

Now consider the mid-point of $\hat A$ and $\hat B$,

$$M=\frac{\hat A + \hat B}{2}$$

If the projection of $\hat x$ on the ray $\overrightarrow{OM}$ is further along than the projection of $\hat A$ or $\hat B$, then $\hat x$ is between $\hat A$ and $\hat B$, that is, if $\; \hat x \cdot M > \hat A \cdot M \; \; (=\hat B \cdot M)$, then $\hat x$ is between $\hat A$ and $\hat B$, otherwise not.

Comment: How would one calculate the interception point $Y$ with $\overleftrightarrow{XY}$ being the shortest distance of $X$ to $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the geodesic line $AB$.
**Hint:** Calculate the angle $\theta =\angle XCP$ where $P$ is a point on the line and $C$ is the center of the sphere. For instance with $\cos \theta =\frac{\vec{CX}\cdot \vec{CP}}{|\vec{CX}|\cdot |\vec{CP}|}=\frac{\vec{CX}\cdot \vec{CP}}{r^2}$, where $r$ is the length of the sphere's radius and $\vec{CX}, \vec{CP}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. This angle is proportional to the geodesic distance between $P$ and $X$.

What you have to do then, is to find the point $P$ for which the angle is smallest.